# Unable to create java classes under maven project folders

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0cb.png)

I have created a maven project under SVN branches folder(attached screenshot).But i am unable to create java class files under dao,domain,etc.. folders.When i create java class. It is appearing under default package.Please explain me whether it is right process to create maven project like this.

Comment: What IDE are you using? I don't see a screenshot

Comment: unable to create java class - What this means? are you getting any error?

Comment: Is your Java class declared in a package dao, domain, etc...

Comment: Whys is your pom.xml located inside `test` folder ?

Comment: I have created project like as same as maven project structure. When I try to create DAO classes under DAO folder the class file is appearing in default package.@Sundarraj Govindasamy

Comment: This is wrong. Your pom.xml should be present at the same level as the src folder. That is, inside the branches/project folder.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the `.project` and `.classpath` and `.settings` folder and then re-import the project again.

Comment: I am using Jboss Developer Studio...@Heri

Comment: When I try to create class files ..it's appearing in default package instead dao,domain folders.I have created these folders under SVN branches....@David soroko